# jquery onclick not running magento 2

Tags: jquery, magento, magento2

I create a module, inside the phtml file, I want to add a jQuery that show alert when radio button is clicked. However, nothing is happening when I click the button (no error, no alert), but when I try to copy and paste the similar code using Firebug, the script work.

It just like Magento 2 didn't execute the code.

What did I miss?

My code inside myfile.phtml is as follow:

```
        <div class="payment-method-billing-address">
         <script>
            require(['jquery'],function($){

                $('input[name=answer]').on('click', function(){
                    alert('You have selected a button');
                });

            });
        </script>

<form method="POST" action="../mymodule" >

<input type="radio" name="answer" value="A" required/>Apple

</form>
```

Comment: just take a look this link, may be solve your issue http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111564/jquery-not-working-in-checkout-page-magento-2/111575#111575

Answer (score 0):

Use change instead of click in input type radio

```
$('input[name=answer]').change(function(){
alert('You have selected a button');
});
```